# Proper reference for the International System of Units

Tags: resource-recommendations, units, si-units, metrology

I would like to cite a relevant document that guides usage of SI units. It seems like currently there are two nearly identical literature sources:

1. 8th edition of [SI Brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) issued by [BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/en/about-us/), **2006**;
2. NIST special Publication 330 "[The International System of Unit](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2016/12/07/sp330.pdf)s", **2008**.

Which one should be used for the reference? Also, both of them lack IDs such as ISBN or DOI (I cannot find any), so how to cite the right source (preferably BibLaTeX example, if possible)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the BIPM one – the NIST describes itself as ‘United States version of the English text of the eighth edition (2006) of the International Bureau of Weights and Measures publication Le Système International d’ Unités (SI)’.

When I've cited it, it's been as

> BIPM. *Le Système international d’unités / The International System of Units (‘The SI Brochure’)*. Bureau international des poids et mesures, eighth edition, 2006. URL `http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/`, ISBN 92-822-2213-6.

Or...

```
@Book{si-brochure,
  title =        {Le Syst\`eme international d'unit\'es / The
                  International System of Units (`The {SI} Brochure')},
  publisher =    {Bureau international des poids et mesures},
  author =       {{BIPM}},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url =          {http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/},
  edition =      {Eighth},
  isbn =         {92-822-2213-6},
  year =         2006
}
```

Or for after the 2019 redefinition:

> BIPM. *Le Système international d’unités / The International System of Units (‘The SI Brochure’)*. Bureau international des poids et mesures, ninth edition, 2019. URL `http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/`, ISBN 978-92-822-2272-0.

```
@Book{si-brochure,
  title =        {Le Syst\`eme international d'unit\'es / The
                  International System of Units (`The {SI} Brochure')},
  publisher =    {Bureau international des poids et mesures},
  author =       {{BIPM}},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url =          {http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/},
  edition =      {Ninth},
  isbn =         {978-92-822-2272-0},
  year =         2019
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The BIPM one, not the NIST one.  The PDF file has an ISBN which is 92-822-2213-6